# Reading Text with Accent - Python

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, quoted-printable, diacritics

I did some script in python that connects to GMAIL and print a email text... But, often my emails has words with "accent". And there is my problem...

For example a text that I got: "PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE" should be printed as "PLANO DE SAÚDE".

How can I turn legible my email text? What can I use to convert theses letters with accent?

Thanks,

---

The code suggested by Andrey, works fine on windows, but on Linux I still getting the wrong print:

```
>>> b = 'PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE'
>>> s = b.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
>>> print s
PLANO DE SÃDE
```

---

Rafael,

Thanks, you are correct about the word, it was misspelled. 
But the problem still the same here. Another example: 
CORRECT WORD: obersevação

```
>>> b = 'Observa=C3=A7=C3=B5es'
>>> s = b.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
>>> print s
ObservaÃ§Ãµes
```

I am using Debian with UTF-8 locale:

```
>>> :~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

---

Andrey,

Thanks for your time. I agree with your explanation, but still with same problem here. Take look in my test:

```
   s='Observa=C3=A7=C3=B5es'
   s2= s.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')

   >>> print s

   Observa=C3=A7=C3=B5es

   >>> print s2

   ObservaÃ§Ãµes

   >>> import locale

   >>> ENCODING = locale.getpreferredencoding()

   >>> print s.encode(ENCODING)
   Observa=C3=A7=C3=B5es

   >>> print s2.encode(ENCODING)
   ObservaÃ§Ãµes

   >>> print ENCODING
   UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This encoding is called Quoted-printable. In your example, you have a string (Python's `unicode`) encoded in UTF-8 bytes (Python's `str`) encoded in quoted printable bytes. So the right way to get a string value is:

```
>>> b = 'PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE'
>>> s = b.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
>>> print s
PLANO DE SÚDE
```

**Update:** There might be some issues with the console conding though. `s` holds a fully correct Unicode string value (of Python type `unicode`). But when you use the `print` statement, the value *must* be converted to bytes (Python's `str`) in order to be written to OS file descriptor number `1` (the standard output pipe). So the `print` statement implementation checks your console encoding, then makes some guesses and prints the results. In fact, in Python 2 the results will be different for printing from the interactive shell, running your process non-interactively and running your process while redirecting the output to a file.

The best way to output encoded strings in Python 2 is not agreed upon. Two ways that make most sense are:

1) Use `locale`'s encoding guess and manually encode strings.

```
import locale
ENCODING = locale.getpreferredencoding()

print s.encode(ENCODING)
```

2) Use an encoding option (command-line, hard-coded or whatever).

```
from getopt import getopt
ENCODING = 'UTF-8'
opts, args = getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['encoding='])
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '--encoding':
        ENCODING = arg

print s.encode(ENCODING)
```

**Update 2:** If nothing helps and you still sure that your console encoding and font are set to UTF-8, then try this:

```
import sys, os
ENCODING = 'UTF-8'
stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb')
s = u'привет' # Don't forget to use a Unicode literal staring with u''
stdout.write(s.encode(ENCODING))
```

At this point you *must* see the Russian word `привет` in cyrillic character set in your console :)

If this is the case, then you should use this binary `stdout` instead of normal `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Andrey, this solution worked fine on Windows. But on Linux the character still unreadable:

Answer (score 0):

Your string is wrong, look:

```
'PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE' == 'PLANO DE S\xc3\x9aDE'
```

Where is the missing "A" in SAÚDE?

If you decode `'PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE'` as a quoted-printable, you will get only 'PLANO DE SÚDE'.

Running this code here on linux (Ubuntu 9.10):

```
>>> b = 'PLANO DE S=C3=9ADE'
>>> s = b.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
>>> print s
PLANO DE SÚDE
```