# Python: raw_input should be converted to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, raw-input

I get the users Input with raw_input(). This Input is stored in a variable. 
How can I cast this variable to be Unicode. I Need this for further executions.

```
 userinput = raw_input("Hello. What is your Name?")
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068581/python-raw-input-odd-behavior-with-accents-containing-strings . Can't you use Python 3? That would make working with Unicode really easier.

Comment: No I Need to use Python2...

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: string = raw_input(...).decode(sys.stdin.encoding) always gives me an error message, saying sys is not available

Comment: @Judith: you need to `import sys` to use it.

Comment: Thank you, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jst call the "decode"  method on the result of "raw_input". Matter is, you need to know the encoding of the terminal where the input was made:

```
import sys

value = raw_input("bla bla bla").decode(sys.stdin.encoding or 'utf-8')
```

But yu really should use Python 3

Comment: Thanks for the answer.